# Is there a Sizeup alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, window-management

I use a piece of software on my mac called Size Up, which you can see here:  http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/

It allows me to control the position of windows on screen using only my keyboard.  I'd really love something like this for Ubuntu, but can't find anything of the sort.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the compiz grid plugin does exactly that ... you can access it through the CCSM interface

If you do not have it then go to the software center and search for ccsm ( it will be the first one; starting with "Advanced")

Open it when/if installed and go to the "grid" plugin; insert wanted parameters to your choice.

Hope it works for you!

btw, CCSM stands for "Compiz Config Settings Manager"

Comment: Love it!  Grid works great for me after some troubleshooting

Comment: Best to search the software center for "Compiz."  If you search for "ccsm" you will get a German magazine (Ausgabe) selling for US $10.50 :)